# How to build curlpp on Mac OSx 10.8

Tags: c++, curl, makefile, libcurl, curlpp

I would like to try the C++ wrapper for libcurl; curlpp. The documentation seems to be non-existent. I am following the steps that I found here:

http://wiki.hartungdesign.net/docs:mac:builds:curlpp

This basically just says do the typical
1. ./configure (with some args) 
2. make

'make' is failing with the following error:

> Making all in src
>   Making all in utilspp
>   /bin/sh ../../libtool --silent --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include/curlpp -I../../include    -g  -W -Wall -Werror     -MT LifetimeLibrary.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/LifetimeLibrary.Tpo -c -o LifetimeLibrary.lo LifetimeLibrary.cpp
>   In file included from LifetimeLibrary.cpp:1:0:
>   ../../include/utilspp/singleton/SingletonHolder.hpp:27:19: fatal error: cassert: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

Has anyone run into this while building this lib on Mac? Do I need to edit the MakeFile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Download curlpp from [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/curlpp/downloads/list) Open Makefile

Remove

```
SUBDIRS = src include examples doc
```

Add

```
SUBDIRS = src include doc

$cd /curlpp-0.7.3/
$make
$sudo make install
```

Comment: Hi Parag Bafana any idea how to build curlpp for iOS