# Can't use curlpp with Xcode even though library is included

Tags: c++, xcode, makefile, curlpp

I am trying to use curlpp in my Xcode c++ project, but even though I added the library to the target in the project settings, I'm told "file not found" for the line

```
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
```

I probably did something wrong, but I'm not sure what. I followed [some instuctions](http://wiki.hartungdesign.net/docs:mac:builds:curlpp) together with another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884760/how-to-build-curlpp-on-mac-osx-10-8) (not long). Here are my exact steps:

1. I downloaded the source from [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/curlpp/downloads/list)
2. I unzipped it etc., then I ran `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/man
   --infodir=/usr/local/info --without-boost`
3. I changed a line in the Makefile: `SUBDIRS = src include examples doc` to `SUBDIRS = src include doc` (removed "examples")
4. I ran `make`
5. I ran `sudo make install`

Everything ran without problems. So I wanted to include the library:

1. Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries -> "+" -> Add Other
2. If I understood correctly, the lib must be in `/usr/local`
3. I found `libcurlpp.0.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib`
4. It's a hidden folder, so I copied it to the project directory and added it to the project
5. I hit compile.
6. Xcode told me `'curlpp/cURLpp.hpp' file not found`

Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm still on the switch from ruby/javascript/python to c++! :)

Comment: Header files and libraries are distinct things. You need to add the path to that `curlpp` directory to your compiler's include file locations.

Comment: @Vincent any idea how to create iOS compatible libcurlpp.0.dylib or  libcurlpp.a

Comment: @Pran no idea, sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are linking ok, but if Xcode can't find the header it means you don't have the header search path set up properly.
Go to Build Settings --> Header Search Path and add the path to your header. Since you are including 'curlpp/cURLpp.hpp' you path has to be the folder containing the folder 'curlpp'.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was missing. I knew I had to do something else, but it was quite hard to google! Thank you!